# How can I reduce multiple cells to zero by subtracting

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is my first time to post and I'm a little out of my depth with what I need Excel to do.

I'm looking for some help to create a few formulas.  I have attached a spreadsheet. What I'd like to be able to do is take the €800 in the Payment column and reduce the Outstanding Balances with it. I need formulas for each of the Outstanding Balances cells which would allow me with the €800 to reduce in order the Older, then 90 Days, then 60 Days and 30 Days columns to zero and lastly would reduce the Current column to €221 (€661-€400).

Is this possible?  Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

[Accounts Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hLROsGfq78HuaGxcUpSuqFYHbgswzSRTdklEvEHMqmY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add 2 extra lines on the Outstanding Balances. You can use only one but this way is clearer.

On the first new line use the Minimum function to verify the amount paid in each segment, deduced the amount already paid. For example:

```
=MIN(B4,SUM($E$9:$E$14)-SUM(C5:$F5))
```

Then subtract the corresponding Payment from the "old" Outstanding Balance.

Result:
[image]

Comment: That excellent! Thanks Eduardo for your help, much appreciated.